# Rails: How to put stuff in header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dom, hyperlink, ruby-on-rails-5, head

In my Rails App I included OneSignal which requires the following link to be placed in the head of the document:

```
<link href='/manifest.json' rel='manifest'>
```

Unfortunately with Rails I cannot put this link there, because the entire layout gets rendered inside the body.

While this ...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("head").append("<link href='/manifest.json' rel='manifest'>");
});
```

seems to work in development mode, it does not work in production.

How can I add this link to my head section of the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `<link href='/manifest.json' rel='manifest'>` in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`.

Comment: That's what I mean, when I do that, in the browser it gets appended to the document body ...

Comment: Not if you add it in the <head> tag.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to make a site wide change (adding the script to every page on the site) you can pick the page you want to put it on and add to the .htmlerb file

```
<%= content_for :header %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "script.js" %>
<%= end %>
```

[`javascript_include_tag`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/javascript_include_tag) will allow you to send content from the controller to the header and if script.js is in your app/assets/javascript directory, that will be added to the header.

Another option is to make a [specific layout](http://railscasts.com/episodes/7-all-about-layouts?autoplay=true) and have the pages that need the script use that layout, by calling it in the controller like so:

```
def users_index
@user= User.find(params[:id])
layout: users_index layout 
end
```

That will load the `users_index_layout.html.erb` file from app/views/layouts...if it exists, and complain loudly if it does not.